Url rewrite on iis that contains /p/ and ends with /
I am trying to write rewrite rule the contains /p/ and ends with /
my rule is below
the rule is match for this url:
https://mysite.co.il/a/p/11/
but not match for this url:
https://mysite.co.il/p/11/
What is wrong with my rule?
<rule name="Remove trailing slash from /p/ URLs" stopProcessing="true">
        <!-- Match URLs that contain /p/ and end with a trailing slash -->
        <match url="^(.*)/p/(.*)/$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <conditions>
            <!-- Ensure it's not a physical file or directory -->
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <!-- Redirect to URL without trailing slash -->
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}/p/{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>


Because the second URL passes p/11/ to the rule engine, which clearly doesn't match your rule. Go and revise your regular expression please.

@LexLi both urls has p/11/
What do I have to change in my regular expression?

You have to search for resources that teach you further on regular expressions. The other URL passes a/p/11/ to the rule engine, so a good enough rewrite rule should be able to handle both, not just one.

@LexLi I really appreciate your help. Can you help me to fix this Regex?

@YosiHavia More accurately, the url you rewrite should contain p/ instead of /p/.

Try to use ^((.*/)?p/(.*))/$ to match, and change the url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" in your action
